# JavaFx event keypress click outside the interface

Tags: javafx

The javafx keyevent statement is as follows

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
        System.out.println("A key was pressed");
    }
});
```

I see it only works when a click event occurs on the interface.If I shrink the scene it won't work.I want to receive events outside the interface.I want to get the event when I press "CTR + V"

Can it work? if it can please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons you won't be able to do that in a easily way, perhaps you will need to use a global library as keylogger but remember you will need to be responsible to stop the logger after you application ends.

take a look to this project: 
https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook